# Why does spray return ok as response body?

Tags: scala, http, routes, spray

When I created spray router like that:

```
  path("test") {
             get {
               complete
               {
                 StatusCodes.OK
               }
             }
         }
```

And send simple get request I got:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: spray-can/1.3.1
Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2015 11:34:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 2

OK
```

Why `OK` is returned in the body? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think this is a bug.
Spray assumes the body of the 'complete' statement is the response body and it will find an implicit conversion from the body return type to something Spray can serialise and apparently it can find such a conversion for a StatusCode.

To specify a specific status code you should use

```
complete(status: StatusCode[, value: T])
```

In your example, just

```
path("test") {
  get {
    complete(StatusCodes.OK)
  }
}
```

Comment: To expand on this: `complete(status)` uses the `fromStatusCode` marshaller which automatically uses the `defaultText` for the entity: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/marshalling/BasicToResponseMarshallers.scala#L13. As hinted here you can use `complete(StatusCodes.OK, HttpEntity.Empty)` or even `complete(HttpEntity.Empty)` to just create a successful 200 response.